# jeditable inline editing , recently updated value not showing when the page loads. shows default click to edit

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jeditable

I am using jeditable plugin to update some values in my textarea inline. When I update them the values are processed in a  file  `save.php` and the value is stored in a table record in the database and the field is updated.

However my problem is once I have already updated the record and when I load or refresh the page, I cannot see the updated value in the field, the default click to edit is displayed until I click and edit the value in which case it displays the new value. I have read on other posts that the save.php should echo out the value to be displayed in the field.

My save.php code

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['suck'])){
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('inline_database');
$data = $_POST['suck'];
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `form_data` VALUES('','$data')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `form_data` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$retrieve_result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retrieve_result)){
  $get_id = $row['id'];
}
echo $get_id;
}
?>
```

My function code which is inside the index.html

```
 $(".editable_textarea").editable("http://localhost/newedit/save.php", { 
  indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
  loadurl : "http://localhost/newedit/save.php",
  type   : 'textarea',
  submitdata: { _method: "post" },

  //id   : 'elementid',
  //name : 'newvalue',
  select : true,
  submit : 'OK',
  cancel : 'cancel',
  cssclass : "editable",
  tooltip   : "Click to edit ",
  });
```

My jeditable.js file

```
var blue =
$.fn.editable.defaults = {
    name       : 'suck',
    id         : 'id',
    type       : 'text',
    width      : 'auto',
    height     : 'auto',
    event      : 'click.editable',
    onblur     : 'cancel',
    loadtype   : 'GET',
    loadtext   : 'Loading...',
    placeholder: 'click to edit',
    loaddata   : {},
    submitdata : {},
    ajaxoptions: {}
};
```

The Jeditable plugin documentation is [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

And this is the live [Demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html).